# Why is pylance unable to resolve the local relative path import (VSCode)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, pylance

Environment:

- Python 3.6.9
- VSCode
- Pylance

The structure of my workspace in VSCode is:

```
.../sync
├── README.rm
├── script-program-1
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── queries.py
│   └── sync.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── logging.yaml
│   └── sync_config.py
└── requirements.txt
```

I've added `"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./lib"]` to settings.json located in sync\.vscode.

The issue is that within the sync.py script I'm having issues importing lib.queries.
If I try `from .lib.queries import *` pylance doesn't complain but it fails with the error `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

If I instead use `from lib.queries import *` python3 works as intended but pylance complains saying `Import "lib.queries" could not be resolved(PylancereportMissingImports)`

What can I change so that the import works AND pylance doesn't have an issue with it?

**Update**
If I add ./script-program-1 to the settings.json python.analysis.extraPaths the problem goes away. The issue I have with this is that this project could have hundreds of "script-program-X" folders and all of them may have their own local import files. Updating this extraPaths variable for every one of them, on ever VSCode machine i work with, is not ideal.

I've tried using a variable like "./${relativeFileDirname}" as well as wild cards like "./**" and "./*but none of these work.

I know that the issue is caused because the workspace root is the sync folder and not script-program-1 but this is how I want it set up. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Feels like switching to Jedi for the project should work or you'd have to create multiple roots for all the directories